# Way to compute large lists

Tags: python, large-data

Suppose, I need to count collisions for various schemes of hashes.
Number of elements in input sequence is 1e10^8 and more.
Don't know how to count this analytically, so using brute-force.

It's obvious not to keep this list of hashes in RAM.
That is the best way to write a code for my needs? Should i dump it in database or something? What libraries are preferred to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest keeping a set of files, each one named with a prefix of the hashes contained within it (for example, if you use a prefix length of 6, then the file named `ffa23b.txt` might contain the hashes `ffa23b11d4334`, `ffa23b712f3`, et cetera). Each time you read a hash, you append it to the file with the name corresponding to the first N characters of the hash.

You can also use [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to quickly rule out a large fraction of the hashes as unique, without having to store all of the hashes in memory. That way, you only have to fall back to searching through a given prefix file if the check against the bloom filter says that you might have actually seen it before - something that will happen rarely.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: if you have some gigabytes of RAM, use Python dictionaries, it's the easiest way to implement (and probably the faster to run). You can do something like this:

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> for i in some_iterator:
        mydict[i] = ''
```

And then check if the key exists in the mapping:

```
>>> 0 in mydict
True

>>> 123456789 in mydict
False
```

**Long answer**: you can use a persistent key-value store, like [GDBM](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gdbm.html) (it looks like Berkeley DB) or another kind of database -- but this approach will be *way* slower than using just Python dictionaries; on the other hand, with this approach you'll have persistance (if you need).

You can understand GDBM as a dictionary (key-value store) that is persisted in a single file. You can use it as follows:

```
>>> import gdbm
>>> kv = gdbm.open('my.db', 'cf')
```

Then the file `my.db` will be created (see [Python GDBM documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gdbm.html) to understand what `cf` means).

But it has some limitations, as supporting only strings as keys and values:

```
>>> kv[0] = 0
Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
TypeError: gdbm mappings have string indices only

>>> kv['0'] = 0
Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
TypeError: gdbm mappings have string elements only

>>> kv['0'] = '0'
```

You can populate a gdbm database with all your keys having a dummy value:

```
>>> for i in some_iterator:
        kv[str(i)] = ''
```

And then check if the key exists in the mapping:

```
>>> '0' in kv
True

>>> '123456789' in kv
False
```

Comment: how to found collisions this way?

Comment: For each input that will generate a hash, you should: 1) check if the hash does exist in `kv` (if yes, there's a collision). 2) add this input as being one o the possible generators for this hash (something like: `kv[hash] = kv[hash] + [input]` -- you should create `kv[hash]` as a `list` in the first time this hash was generated).